# Read multiple TFRecord files with keras::tfrecord_dataset

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets

I am getting started with Keras, and would like to create a dataset from multiple TFRecord files.

Below is the code I have so far.

```
 dataset <- tfrecord_dataset(filenames) %>%
  dataset_map(function(example_proto) {
    features <- list(
      label = tf$FixedLenFeature(shape(), tf$float32),
      a = tf$FixedLenFeature(shape(), tf$float32),
      b = tf$FixedLenFeature(shape(), tf$float32),
      c = tf$FixedLenFeature(shape(), tf$float32),
      d = tf$FixedLenFeature(shape(), tf$float32)

 )

    features <- tf$parse_single_example(example_proto, features)
    x <- list(features$a,
              features$b, 
              features$c
              features$d
    )
    y <- tf$one_hot(tf$cast(features$label, tf$int32), 3L)
    list(x, y)
  }) %>%
  dataset_shuffle(150) %>%
  dataset_batch(16)
```

With a single tfrecord (e.g. file1 with features a,b and c), everything works fine.

If I add a second tfrecord file2 with feature d such that filenames = c(file1, file2), then I get the following error:

```
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
InvalidArgumentError: Feature: d (data type: float) is required but could not be found.
```

Is there an efficient way to read multiple tfrecord files with tfrecord_dataset?

Thanks..!

Answer (score 0):

At least as of TensorFlow 1.14 you can pass an argument `default_value` to `tf$io$FixedLenFeature` that will be used in the case where that column is missing from the file.

From the docs:

- `default_value`: Value to be used if an example is missing this feature. It must be compatible with `dtype` and of the specified shape.